# Using Buttons in React Material UI Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have made a table using Material UI where I have two buttons in the first column of every row. I wish to edit/delete rows  on clicking these but Im stuck on logic. Is it even possible with my implementation ? If not then what's the preferred way of doing so?

```
render() {
  var deleteIcon =
  (<IconButton onClick={console.log("delete")}>
    <DeleteIcon color="secondary" />
  </IconButton>
  );

  const editIcon = (
    <IconButton onClick={console.log("edited")}>
      <EditIcon color="primary" />
    </IconButton>
  );

return(
  <TableBody>
   {this.state.serviceData.map(n => {
    return (
     <TableRow key={n.id}>
      <TableCell style={styles.editor} component="th" scope="row">
        {deleteIcon}
        {editIcon}
      </TableCell>
     <TableCell>{n.domain}</TableCell>
   <TableCell>{n.service_name}</TableCell>
  </TableCell>
 </TableRow>
)};
```

And my result is : 
[image: Image showing my table]

Comment: You should give `onPress` a function, but it seems like you are giving it simply `null` (console.log runs every time your component renders, and the result of that gets to the `onPress`, which is `null`). So you should add a method to the class like: `editItem` and `deleteItem` and pass that instead as the value for `onPress`

Comment: You mean going onPress={this.editItem.bind()} ?

Comment: You shouldn't really do the bind on `render`, because `bind` creates another function with the values attached or bind, so it would create a function every time the component renders. Bind `this` to the class method on `constructor` like `this.editItem = this.editItem.bind(this)`(only bind on instance creation, one time only, like any other class method) or use syntax sugar `editItem = () => {}` (arrow function) to automatically bind this to class method.

Comment: Looks like onPress is not a valid handler.. However on binding the function on render and  calling it with onClick works! Any idea how to pass in my row details now as well? Usually I would do bind(this,data) and use data but how to work here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on @st4rl00rd's comment, I was able to tie the buttons using :

```
const editIcon = (
      <IconButton onClick={this.editItem}>
        <EditIcon color="primary" />
      </IconButton>
    );
```

and binding them in the constructor. I was able to get the selected row data by doing :

```
       <TableBody>
            {this.state.serviceData.map(n => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={n.id} onClick={this.getData.bind(this,n)}>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have recreated your problem and solved the problem with my logic.

I passed the `index` of each element as a parameter to the handler functions.

Eg:

```js
const editIcon = index => (
      <IconButton onClick={() => this.editComponent(index)}>
        <EditIcon color="primary" />
      </IconButton>
    );
```

**DELETION**

For deletion, pass the index as params to the handler function and delete the element at specified index using `splice` operator.

```js
deleteComponent(index) {
    const serviceData = this.state.serviceData.slice();
    serviceData.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ serviceData });
  }
```

**EDITING**

I have used a state called `index` to keep track of the index the user is currently editing. Initially the `index` is -1

So whenever the user clicks edit button the `editedIndex` is updated.

```js
editComponent(index) {
    this.setState({ editedIndex: index });
  }
```

I created two TextField Component which is shown at the specified cell (the cell where editbutton is clicked)

```js
const editDomain = (
      <TextField
        id="domain"
        label="Domain"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={this.state.editedDomain}
        margin="normal"
        onChange={this.handleChange('editedDomain')}
      />
    );
```

So Whenever the rendering component Index is equal to editedIndex the editing Compomemts are shown at corresponding Tablecell

```js
<TableCell>
  {serviceData.indexOf(n) === editedIndex
    ? editDomain
    : n.domain}
</TableCell>
```

Comment: the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/j73yvyp9qv is showing errors now

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to do this
[image]

I have done same using React-Table here is the link for my project repo you can consider this as an example:

https://github.com/AdnanShah/ReactJS-KretaHub-/blob/Thank_You_Init/src/app/routes/dashboard/routes/Default/rows.js